# How to get Image URL based on name

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

My JSON contains only name of the food categories, Looks like below

```
[
{
    "cu_id": "2",
    "cuisine_type": "American"
},
{
    "cu_id": "24",
    "cuisine_type": "Sandwich"
},
{
    "cu_id": "17",
    "cuisine_type": "Seafood"
},
{
    "cu_id": "29",
    "cuisine_type": "Sports Bar"
},
{
    "cu_id": "5",
    "cuisine_type": "Steak"
},
{
    "cu_id": "20",
    "cuisine_type": "Sushi"
}
]
```

I want to get default image automatically from Internet by searching 'cuisine_type', How to do that?

Comment: Do you want to search them in Google Images?

Comment: yes, But it should be automatically done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [pixabay](https://pixabay.com/api/docs/) api it's a free RESTful api for searching and retrieving free images and videos released on Pixabay under Creative Commons CC0.

Sending a `GET` request like this :

```
https://pixabay.com/api/?key={ KEY }&q=query&image_type=photo
```

where :

- Key : the api key you get after creating an account
- q : the queried object you need to look for
- image_type : what kind of data you need (picture, video)

returned data will be something like this :

```
{
"total": 4692,
"totalHits": 500,
"hits": [
    {
        "id": 195893,
        "pageURL": "https://pixabay.com/en/blossom-bloom-flower-yellow-close-195893/",
        "type": "photo",
        "tags": "blossom, bloom, flower",
        "previewURL": "https://static.pixabay.com/photo/2013/10/15/09/12/flower-195893_150.jpg"
        "previewWidth": 150,
        "previewHeight": 84,
        "webformatURL": "https://pixabay.com/get/35bbf209db8dc9f2fa36746403097ae226b796b9e13e39d2_640.jpg",
        "webformatWidth": 640,
        "webformatHeight": 360,
        "imageWidth": 4000,
        "imageHeight": 2250,
        "imageSize": 4731420,
        "views": 7671,
        "downloads": 6439,
        "favorites": 1,
        "likes": 5,
        "comments": 2,
        "user_id": 48777,
        "user": "Josch13",
        "userImageURL": "https://static.pixabay.com/user/2013/11/05/02-10-23-764_250x250.jpg",
    },
    {
        "id": 14724,
        ...
    },
    ...
]
}
```

for more detail visit this [link](https://pixabay.com/api/docs/)